# How do I keep the app f.lux in bedtime mode during the day?

Tags: f.lux

How do I keep the app [f.lux](https://justgetflux.com/) in bedtime mode during the day? I want to be able to toggle f.lux on all the time

This app is great, especially if you are coding on a high energy 27inch Apple cinema display.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### How do I keep the app Flux in bedtime mode during the day?

Just set the "Daytime" and "At night" settings to be the same.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to adjust the bedtime settings and it kept reverting...